# How many caste are there in Hinduism?

Tags: caste-system

If one searches Caste on google images, the first few images they would be greeted with is this:

[image]

[However on wikipedia,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caste_system_in_India#:%7E:text=There%20are%203%2C000%20castes%20and,related%20to%20a%20specific%20occupation.) the following is written:

> There are 3,000 castes and 25,000 sub-castes in India, each related to a specific occupation

How does this number of Caste and the most popular division of Caste as the five regions of Brahma relate?

Comment: Brahmanas originate from the face, Kshatriyas from the arms, Vaishyas from the thighs & Shudras from the feet. Varnashankara castes like Kayasthas, Vaidyas, Gopalakas (Yadavs), Sutas etc originated due to inter-caste marriage. Most of these varna-shankaras are considered as Sat-shudras i.e the are touchable. It is the Asat-shudra varnashankaras who are regarded as untouchables. Most texts agree that outside the 4 main caste groups, there are 36 varnashankara castes.